# How to format enumerated lists from latex to docx

Tags: ms-word, latex, pandoc, pdflatex

I have several hundred Word documents to generate from latex sources, TEX to DOCX. Pandoc works just fine with one little glitch -- enumerated lists in LaTeX are rendered with Roman numerals in the DOCX output files.

I can't seem to find any documentation that addresses this issue, and Word documents with lists numbered with Roman numerals are not acceptable with my application.

Does anyone have any idea where the documentation on this is? My LaTex lists are as usual

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Pandoc filters are able to change nearly any kind of behaviour including this. That portion of the documentation is at https://pandoc.org/filters.html. The main portion of the docs is at https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html. We don't know what formatting you want instead though, so it's difficult to make a recommendation. If you want bullet points for example, you should be using latex itemize instead of enumerate. A quick bash/python script could easily make the change for you (either permanently or as an intermediate processing step if you want to store the result in temporary files).

Comment: Thanks. The issue seems to be in Word itself. Word thinks that the formatting to apply to numbered lists is lower case Roman numerals. I've munged OOXML before, but don't really want to do so now. If I could write a filter to instruct Word to use Arabic numerals, it probably would work. Maybe I'll try that,

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually an answer, more of a workaround.

If I convert from LaTeX to RTF, everything works like it's supposed to, and Winword will natively open RTF files.

I don't know how my users will respond ("What's a RTF? Is it like a WTF?"), but at this point I don't really care.